# R - Iterate through variable names

Tags: json, r, loops, variables, for-loop

I'm trying to iterate (*for*) through variables. This is the code:

```
json_YR_FKA <- getURL('https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/b7i1ej7i?apikey=-')
json_9A_BTE <- getURL('https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/a83t52cg?apikey=-')
```

I will have two variables: json_YR_FKA / json_9A_BTE

```
matriculas <- ls()
matriculas <- str(matriculas)
matriculas
```

> matriculas
>   [1] "json_9A_BTE" "json_YR_FKA"

And now, I need to do some things with both variables, so I have a *for* iteration:

```
for (i in 1:total){
   avion <- fromJSON(matriculas[i])  
   # boring code
}
```

My idea is to do this:

First iteration: fromJSON(json_9A_BTE)
Second iteration: fromJSON(json_YR_FKA)

But at the beginning of the first iteration I get this:

> fromJSON(matriculas[i])
>   Error in fromJSON(matriculas[1]) : unexpected character 'j'

And I don't know why.

Anyone?

Thanks in advance.

Luis

Comment: Is the length of your matriculas vector 2? (`length(matriculas)`) or are the variables stored in a list? if they are in a list try putting double square brackets around your "i" in the loop `avion <- fromJSON(matriculas[[i]])`

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, Collin. The lenght is 2 (total <- length(matriculas). But it could be any number in the future. I have tried > fromJSON(matriculas[[1]])
Error in fromJSON(matriculas[[1]]) : unexpected character 'j' ... I get the same :-/

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you're taking isn't very R-like, so I'm guessing you're coming from Python or some other language?

First off, I'm not sure what packages you're using. Where does getURL() come from?  Which JSON package are you using?  I suggest jsonlite since it can just pull data in from the url.

```
library(jsonlite)

myUrls <- c(json_YR_FKA='https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/b7i1ej7i?apikey=-',
            json_9A_BTE='https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/a83t52cg?apikey=-')

matriculas <- lapply(myUrls, fromJSON) #Provides a list of your data.

f_doSomething <- function(dat) {
    #boring code that puts data into 'out' variable
    return(out)
    }

avion <- lapply(matriculas, f_doSomething)
```

Comment: I'm coming from .NET, java, pyhton, pascal... so I have a mix of knowledge :-). Thank you very much, I will try your solution. BTW, I'm using: library('RCurl') / library('rjson') / library('RMySQL')

Comment: Good info.  Yeah, unless you're using 'RCurl' for something else I would skip it entirely.  'jsonlite' is a drop-in replacement for 'rjson' and the fromJSON() function that jsonlite provides handles setting up file connections and url downloads on its own.  It does require the 'curl' package for url downloads though, so I suggest installing that as well.  I've found 'curl' to be a bit more sane about how it interfaces with libcurl than 'RCurl' is.

Comment: Hi! I hve been busy, I will try tomorrow your formula :-) thanks!